# Unable to align the text of menu bar to enter, which have vertical bar (black) 100%

Tags: html, css

I had tried a lot to bring these text to center but I didn't succeed, so please someone help me out of this. The problem is I am trying to bring only the text to center and rest of them must have be in same format.

Html code:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Main page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssstyles1.css" /></head></head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">news</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contactus </a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 05px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;

}

li {
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 08px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border:10px;
     display:inline-block;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #cccccc;
    color:black;

}

.active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add the left:50% to move your listed objects. Change your css like this.

`li {
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    left:50%;
}`